# Woocommerce cart items not working in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I have a simple function which return cart items and when I call this function in function.php I have an error .

```
<?php 
class Theme { 
 public static $version;
 function __construct() { 
  $theme = wp_get_theme();
  self::$version = $theme['Version'];   
  $this->cart_items(); 
  } 
 function cart_items(){ 
   var_dump(get_users()); 
 } 
new Theme();
```

And I have this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart_contents() on null

Comment: Thank you for your response . I have a theme and inside my function.php i have a class with the cart_items() function , and constructor .

Comment: I have tried you code and the only error is just a missing closing bracket `}`before `new Theme();` … With it your code works.

Comment: Do you have the items of your cart ? can you send mee a screenshot plz ?

Comment: The `var_dump(get_users());` is executed on any page load… No need of a screenshot.

Comment: Rename your cart_items() function as it's probably clashing with another function of the same name. Or make it private. Or add name spacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add this below code
<?php 
class Theme { 
 public static $version;
 function __construct() { 
  $theme = wp_get_theme();
  self::$version = $theme['Version'];   
  $this->cart_items(); 
  } 
 function cart_items(){ 
   var_dump(get_users()); 
 } 
}
new Theme();
```